# What is the timestamp format of deletedAt entry when using sstable2json utility?

Tags: cassandra

I am running a sstable2json export from an existing cassandra cluster. I encounter values such as this in the created json object:

```
'deletedAt': -9223372036854776000L,
```

Is this just a flag that cassandra sets to mark the entry as deleted, or is this an actual timestamp? If so, what is the format of this timestamp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Long.MIN_VALUE means "not deleted."

Comment: Isn't -9223372036854775808L Long.MIN_VALUE? Is the offset calculated from that somehow?